# T-SQL a Power Query (M)

Tags: sql

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar el lenguaje M,y necesito transcribir una consulta en SQL (T-SQL) a dicho lenguaje, es decir:

T-SQL: Select Columna1, Columna 2 FROM table WHERE Columna 3>0

Lenguaje M: ?

Muchas gracias a todxs.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Podrias mostrarnos que intentaste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Son lenguajes para propósitos distintos. La equivalencia sería la siguiente, aunque dependerá del origen de datos, en este caso es de un SQL Server local.

```
let
    Origen = Sql.Database("localhost", "UnaBD", [Query="Select Columna1, Columna2 FROM table WHERE Columna3>0"])
in
Origen
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Roger!